# Magento 2 .focus() not working in template

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, phtml

I have this template:

**CODE PHTML:**

```
<div>
    Content  // this line is OK
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'],function($){
        $(window).load(function() {
            alert("test"); // this line is OK
            $('input').focus(function(){
                console.log("test");  // this line is NOT OK
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I can't execute the line of code for inputs
I do not receive any error but I do not working.

I tried with `setTimeout()` but it still doesn't work.

If you run the line in the console in Chrome then everything is fine.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you replace this:

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    console.log("test");  // this line is NOT OK
});
```

With this?

```
$('body').on('focus', 'input', function() {
    console.log("test");
})
```

If so change `body` to a parent element that is not rendered dynamically.

This uses event delegation so if the `input` element is rendered dynamically via JS it will still work, this may or may not be the issue here it's hard to tell without seeing the full code and page. You can read more about event delegation [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to require the domready like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'domReady!'],function($){
    $(window).load(function() {
        alert("test"); // this line is OK
        $('input').focus(function(){
            console.log("test");  // this line is NOT OK
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense having window load AND domReady!, I would get rid of window load and keep domReady! as we only care about the DOM elements being loaded. But if on window load doesn't work I doubt domReady! will make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['domReady!'], function(){
        document.getElementById('inputId').focus();
    });
</script>
```

From the [docs](https://requirejs.org/docs/api#pageload):

> Note: If the document takes a while to load (maybe it is a very large document, or has HTML script tags loading large JS files that block DOM completion until they are done), using domReady as a loader plugin may result in a RequireJS "timeout" error. If this is a problem either increase the [waitSeconds](https://requirejs.org/docs/api#config-waitSeconds) configuration, or just use domReady as a module and call domReady() inside the require() callback.